# Divide by floating-point number using NEON intrinsics

Tags: android, c, arm, intrinsics, neon

I'm processing an image by four pixels at the time, this on a `armv7` for an Android application.

I want to divide a `float32x4_t` vector by another vector but the numbers in it are varying from circa `0.7` to `3.85`, and it seems to me that the only way to divide is using right shift but that is for a number which is `2^n`.

Also, I'm new in this, so any constructive help or comment is welcomed.

Example:

How can I perform these operations with NEON intrinsics?

```
float32x4_t a = {25.3,34.1,11.0,25.1};
float32x4_t b = {1.2,3.5,2.5,2.0};
//    somthing like this
float32x4 resultado = a/b; // {21.08,9.74,4.4,12.55}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The NEON instruction set does not have a floating-point divide.

If you know *a priori* that your values are not poorly scaled, and you do not require correct rounding (this is almost certainly the case if you're doing image processing), then you can use a reciprocal estimate, refinement step, and multiply instead of a divide:

```
// get an initial estimate of 1/b.
float32x4_t reciprocal = vrecpeq_f32(b);

// use a couple Newton-Raphson steps to refine the estimate.  Depending on your
// application's accuracy requirements, you may be able to get away with only
// one refinement (instead of the two used here).  Be sure to test!
reciprocal = vmulq_f32(vrecpsq_f32(b, reciprocal), reciprocal);
reciprocal = vmulq_f32(vrecpsq_f32(b, reciprocal), reciprocal);

// and finally, compute a/b = a*(1/b)
float32x4_t result = vmulq_f32(a,reciprocal);
```

Comment: I also taught in this kind of solution but i didn't know about vrecpeq_f32, so thank you very much.
I think neon intrinsics needs better documentation about the functions that it has

Comment: @Darkmax: you should download the architecture reference manuals from ARM, rather than relying on the NEON header documentation.