# How I can Find inverse/reciprocal of float variable in Neon

Tags: assembly, neon, cortex-a8

I want to find inverse of number variable which is of type float .
Can any one tell me the instruction available in neon (A9 processor) .
means :

```
 float number = 5.63;
 float inverse = 1/number ; //In neon ??
```

Comment: NEON is for SIMD operations - do you want to calculate the reciprocal for 2 or 4 floats in parallel ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to divide in neon intrinsics by a float number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759897/how-to-divide-in-neon-intrinsics-by-a-float-number)

Comment: @PaulR,I want  do to reciprocal for 4 floats parallel (float32x4_t)

Comment: You should make that clear in your question, but it looks like your question is a duplicate anyway.